# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found when calling servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications

// Servlet File

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Index")
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            
        
        String s = req.getParameter("username");
        
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("Hi " + s);
        
    }
}
```

//home.jsp file

```
    <form action="Index">
        <input type="text" name="username"> <br> 
        <input type="text" name="password"> <br> 
        <input type="submit">
```

I want to print (Hi + username) which is coded on servlet
I am requesting the username from the JSP file but when hit submit I am getting the error

Comment: What Servlet container are you using? Tomcat? Where did you place the file IndexServlet.class?

Comment: yes I am using tomcat

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74771386/getting-classnotfoundexception-or-http-status-404-not-found-when-running-j